# Neo4j Query to Multiple Nodes with Same Relations

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

How should I write the queries to get multiple nodes with the same relationship? For example, with the graph pattern

```
(u:user)-[r:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(s:skill)
```

I want to get users who have, let's say skill 'A' and skill 'B'.
Of course I can't do it like this right?

```
MATCH (u:user)-[r:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(s:skill)
WHERE s.name = "A" AND s.name = "B"
RETURN u.username
```

Here the graph i'm using to query:

[image: Example of graph]

Comment: What is the problem with the query shown in the question? What is the desired output?

Comment: I think the query above won't work because the name property of the skill is not a list. So using the query

s.name = "A" AND s.name = "B"

of course won't give any match in the database.

I want to get the user(s) who have both skill.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I answered your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like this:

```
MATCH (skillA {name : "A"})
MATCH (skillB {name : "B"})
MATCH (u:user)
WHERE (u)-[:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(skillA)
AND (u)-[:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(skillB)
RETURN u.username
```

The query above matches `skillA` and `skillB`. After, the `WHERE` clause will guarantee that only users that have a relationship `:USER_HAS_SKILL` with `skillA` and `skillB` will be matched.

**EDIT:**

From comments:

> I see, that could work! Thank you very much!! But, is there more
>   efficient way? What would the query be like if I want to, let's say,
>   find a user with 10 skills?

```
MATCH (s:skill) WHERE s.name IN ["A", "B"]
MATCH (u:user)-[:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(s)
RETURN u.username
```

This query should make the same work in a more elegant approach. This way you can put all skill names in the array.

Comment: I see, that could work! Thank you very much!!
But, is there more efficient way?

What would the query be like if I want to, let's say, find a user with 10 skills?

Comment: @WilliamStefanHartono I edited my answer. Try it please! :)

Comment: @Bruno your edit doesn't work if he wants to find users who have both A *and* B. That finds users who have A *or* B.

Comment: Yes that is my answer below. :)

Comment: Sorry @NicoleWhite, I mentioned you trying to mention the author of the question.  Also I was not pay attention and posted a query semantically equivalent to your answer. Is not the intention. My mistake. I will rollback the edit.

Comment: Haha no you should keep it as your answer is the selected one! No worries at all.

Comment: When you make [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443892/neo4j-query-to-multiple-nodes-with-same-relations/45444203?noredirect=1#comment77849861_45444203), I did not pay attention to the name of the commenter and assumed that he was the author of the question. Sorry one more time! :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is many skills and you don't want to write it out explicitly, you can do something like this.

```
WITH ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] AS skillset
MATCH (u:User)-[:USER_HAS_SKILL]->(s:Skill)
WHERE s.name IN skillset
WITH skillset, u, count(s) AS matches
WHERE matches = size(skillset)
RETURN u.username;
```